# Using line-height in Chrome CSS in different areas of code

Tags: html, css

I'm learning about the roles of `line-height` and `font-size` in CSS for HTML.

I originally defined the CSS for the `p` tags as such (shown also in the snippet):

```
p {
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

However, I decided later in the block of code that I might want to change the `line-height` to `2.0` instead, so I did the following afterward when following a lecturer who did the same and produced the required results on Udemy:

```
p {
    line-height:2.0;
}
```

I'm a bit confused. I thought that if I declared the `line-height` again later down the code, it would change to the new value I declared, being `2.0` rather than `1.0`

I am using Chrome version 70 but I'm stuck as to why this effect occurs.

```css
/*font-family*/

* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

p {
 font-family: Arial;
}

h1 {
 font-family: Georgia;
}

h1 {
 /*font-size: 200px;*/
 /*font-size: em;*/
/* em is relative font size*/
}

/*font-size*/

body {
 font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 5.0em;
}

p {
 font-size: 2.0em;
 font-weight: bold;
  line-height:1.0;
}

span {
 font-size: 2.0em;
}
/*doubles the size relative to the element it is inside */\
/*so now span is 80px (40 x 2)*/
/*default px side is around 16px*/
/*you can set a default in body */

/*line-height controls height of a given line */
p {
 line-height:2.0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Fonts</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="fontstyles.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Fonts Demo Page</h1>
  Lorem Ipsum.
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span>adipisicing elit</span>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not update the original styles for `p` up in the first block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken comment

```
/*doubles the size relative to the element it is inside */\
```

So the next rule will fail to be applied.

Once you fix that up, I think you will get the results that you expected.

```css
/*font-family*/

* {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

h1 {
  /*font-size: 200px;*/
  /*font-size: em;*/
  /* em is relative font size*/
}


/*font-size*/

body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.0em;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.0;
}

span {
  font-size: 2.0em;
}


/*doubles the size relative to the element it is inside */


/*so now span is 80px (40 x 2)*/


/*default px side is around 16px*/


/*you can set a default in body */


/*line-height controls height of a given line */

p {
  line-height: 2.0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fonts Demo Page</h1>
Lorem Ipsum.
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span>adipisicing elit</span>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: My lord, this CSS really is a pain in the backside! Hahaha thanks so much!

Comment: Only the next rule will fail to be applied. Not all CSS following.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Alohci

Comment: @BobSmith It sucks that CSS should fail silently like that. Feel free to run your CSS through a validator occasionally if you are running into weird issues.

Comment: Use a code editing tool for syntax highlighting. This will allow you to see where you are making mistakes like not ending a comment correctly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting 
https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+code+editors

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using line-height for text elements which do not break in multiple lines since the height that you are putting will have precedence over height, in the case that line-height is bigger than height it will override it and sometime creates confusion by trying to edit that size and not affecting.